# Using the Codeigniter form validation library, how can I ensure at least one letter is entered?

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am using Codeigniter form validation. In my registration form the `Username` field allows only numbers like **123456**. I don't want this to happen.

My validation rule is as follows

```
'rules'=>'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|xss_clean'
```

I want to prevent users entering just numeric strings. Alpha numeric strings are fine, alpha strings are fine, but purely numeric ones are not.

Comment: Can you clarify? What does `I don't want as only number.` mean?

Comment: @Colin: It should be only **alpha numeric**. For example :If I give the **Username** as only number **123456** it should not allowed to register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow only letters

Add `alpha` to your rules and remove `alpha_numeric` from your rules

You can use [this page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) as a point of reference for built in validation rules.

**Edit:**

Since you've clarified now.

To achieve this, there's no built in validation rule. You will need to extend the `Form_validation` library by creating a `libraries/MY_Form_validation.php` file. See [this manual page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) on how to extend libraries.

In this file, create the following function

```
function at_least_one_letter($string) {
    return preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $string);
}
```

Then you can add the validation rule `at_least_one_letter` to your rules.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to accept an answer :) As you appear to be new here, [here's a guide on how to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

According to the codeigniter [user manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference) :

> You can also use any native PHP functions that permit one parameter.

I think in this case `is_int` could be used as your validation rule.

So, for instance:

```
'rules'=>'trim|required|is_int|min_length[6]|xss_clean',
```

Comment: Thank you.. I think **integer** in codeigniter and **is_int and  is_numeric** are same. Is there any way to do in CI rather than using php function?

Comment: You can use the php function directly in your validation rule:
 'rules'=>'trim|required|is_int|min_length[6]|xss_clean',

Comment: As it is coming from a form using `post` it will be a numeric string rather than an integer. You will need to use `is_numeric`

Comment: Thx, I want **!is_int**, I mean it should be **Not a Integer or Numbers**

Comment: Please clarify. Option 1: No numbers, only letters. Option 2: numbers and letters. Option 3: No numbers on their own, a letter must be included.?