# Custom Form_validation library not working

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation

I made a `custom_form_validation.php` file in `application\libraries` which contains:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
  class Custom_form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
    function Custom_form_validation()
    {
      parent::__construct();  
    }

    /* at_least_one_letter() by Ben Swinburne
     * http://stackoverflow.com/a/9218114/1685185
     -----------------------------------------------*/
    public function has_at_least_one_letter( $string ) 
    {
      $result = preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $string);
      if ( $result == FALSE ) $this->set_message('has_at_least_one_letter', 'The %s field must have at least one letter.');
    return $result;
    }
  }
```

Then I load it in a specific controller as:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->library('custom_form_validation');
```

Finally, I use the function `has_at_least_one_letter` as:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'field name', 'has_at_least_one_letter');
```

I don't know what's wrong since I followed the examples given here in SO to construct my own library, specifically the ones about "extends `form_validation`". Did I miss a step or some special part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to make a separate function to run regex validation in CodeIgniter. It allows you to specify regex like so:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'field name', 'regex_match[#[a-zA-Z]#]');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this convenient answer! :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Custom Library extends CI_Form_Validation:

> libraries\MY_Form_validation.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    protected $CI;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

function has_at_least_one_letter($string) {
    $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('has_at_least_one_letter', 'The %s field must have at least one letter.');
    return preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $string);
}
```

then use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'field name', 'has_at_least_one_letter');
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! It works and your syntax is way better than mine :)

Comment: Hello! I had a problem, when I changed the position of `has_at_least_one_letter` in the `set_rules` field, it doesn't work. Like `$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'field name', 'has_at_least_one_letter|is_unique[table.FieldName]');` to `$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'field name', 'is_unique[table.FieldName]|has_at_least_one_letter');`. What do you think?

Comment: u can use rather then.. to set rule min_lengt[1] in set rules...
public function unique($str, $field)
{
 list($table, $column) = explode(',', $field, 2);
 
 $this->CI->form_validation->set_message('unique', 'The %s that you requested is already in use.');
 
 $query = $this->CI->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM {$this->CI->db->dbprefix($table)} WHERE {$column} = '{$str}'");
 $row = $query->row();
 
 return ($row->cnt > 0) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}
$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName', 'ield name', 'unique[DBTABLE,DBFIELD]')

Comment: Thank you, but what I meant is `has_at_least_one_letter` is not working even if I remove `is_unique` :( I copy pasted your code from above and it still doesn't work. Thank you for answering my questions!